# How to update json data if it is changed on the server?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I use the Volley library to fetch json data that changes every 5 seconds,
I want Method to update the data in the app if it changes in the server.

Comment: If you are getting the data from the server every 5 seconds isn't that updating the data in your app?

Comment: Make some research about long polling, web socket, firebase, rethinkdb..

Comment: do you mean to ask how to check if latest data fetched is same as data fetched previously

Comment: yes @BharatMukkala

Comment: The update is brought to the application only when it is restarted

Comment: do u need to write a way of fetching every five seconds? or is that already in place?

Comment: away to fetching every five seconds @ariochdivij666

Comment: recommend using a socket. but if that is not supported, created a service that runs in the background, fetches every 5 seconds writes to a DB or returns the object to the app through the IBinder. Optionally use LiveData and post updates from a background thread, or using RxJava Observables.

Comment: @Mohamed Mesalm since you would store json as an object, it is better to compare individual values in the json objects and check if they are equal

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string to store the json data. Then set it so every five seconds it compares that string to the first string that you  have. And if that boolean method is false than write that data to the app.

```
String json = "{
"Item":"potato"
}

timed command code
String newjson = //your read in code here

if(string json != newjson)
{
json = newjson
//write it to your app here
}
```

Hope this helps as I cant provide direct code since you dont have any in your question.